# how do I tell if an event is fired by .click() or by the user?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to differentiate actual mouse clicks from script generated clicks.How can i do it with jquery?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What automatic trigger scenarios do you want to differentiate? If you're calling `click` itself on an element, set a variable or something.

Comment: Maybe pass a variable with different values when .click() is called and when it's clicked by user. Check the variable to determine where the click originated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check for something that isn't included in a triggered event object.

```
$('div').click(function(e) {
    if ( e.originalEvent ) {
        console.log('actual mouseclick');
    }
}).trigger('click');
```